# Numerical methods for integral eigenvalue equation

Tags: integration, na.numerical-analysis, integral-transforms, integral-kernel

I have an integral equation which is not exactly an eigenvalue type equation, but similar:

$$\int d^3 y\, K(x,y,\lambda) f(y) = f(x)$$

Here $\lambda$ can be thought of as an eigenvalue, so it is expected that only for a discrete set of $\lambda$ we have a solution. $K(x,y,\lambda)$ is some fairly simple expression involving ratios of polynomials and also $\lambda$ appears in a rational fashion.

What would be the typical numerical methods to find the lowest eigenvalue $\lambda$ and eigenfunction $f(x)$?

Actually, we can formulate the question generally: how does one find the eigenfunction corresponding to zero eigenvalue of a linear integral operator that depends on some $\lambda$? The task involves finding the particular $\lambda$ for which the operator has a zero eigenvalue to begin with.

$${\cal O}(\lambda) v = 0$$

Generally ${\cal O}(\lambda)$ doesn't have zero eigenvalues, but for a discrete set of $\lambda$ it does. How can I find it numerically? Probably an iterative procedure would be most cost effective. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve $\int d^3 y\, K(x,y,\lambda) f(y) = f(x)$ I would discretize the coordinates $x\mapsto x_n$, $y\mapsto y_m$, $K(x,y,\lambda)\mapsto K(x_n,y_m,\lambda)\equiv K_{nm}(\lambda)$ and solve the determinant equation
$$\text{det}\,[I-K_{nm}(\lambda)]=0$$
for $\lambda$, when the indices $n,m$ vary over a finite range.

Things would simplify greatly if $K(x,y,\lambda)$ depends only on the difference $x-y$, because then you could Fourier transform and find a $\lambda$ such that $\hat{K}(\xi,\lambda)=1$ for some $\xi$.

Comment: This sounds promising. But as the range of $n$ and $m$ grows it will become harder and harder to compute the determinant directly and I thought an iterative procedure might exist, similarly to finding actual eigenvalues. The lowest eigenvalue can be found by all sorts of tricky iterative procedures, which are usually cheaper than direct methods.

Comment: Unfortunately $K(x,y)$ is not only a function of $x-y$.